# volume cylinder

Tags: geometry, volume

It's a silly question, but still:

Is it possible to calculate the volume of a cylinder only knowing the area $A_1$? (I don't know what it's called. It equals $r \cdot h$.)

[image: cylinder]

Comment: Considering the volume of a cylinder is $V = \pi r^2 h$, knowing this area is enough. So, yes.

Comment: so we know $r \cdot h = A$ then $h = \frac{A}{r}$ so volume is $\pi \cdot r \cdot A$. So if I keep reducing $h$, $r$ keeps increasing, what happens to volume?

Comment: Double the radius and halve the height (so your area is unchanged) and the volume will double

Comment: The answer is yes. See the theorem of Pappus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

The volume of a cylinder is $V = \pi r^2h = \pi(rh) r = \pi A_1 r$.

Even if you fixed the value of $A_1 = rh$, you could vary $r$ ($h$ would change in inverse proportion to keep $A_1$ constant) and that would cause $V$ to change. The point is that, without knowing the value of $r$ (and $h$) separately, you cannot pin down the value of $V$.

Answer (score 0):

No, the area is proportional to $rh$ and the volume to $r^2h$. You can't solve for two parameters with a single equation.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, by the theorem of Pappus, we can compute a volume of revolution by multiplying the area being swept by the length of the path traveled by the center of mass of the area.

We have the center of mass of the area is at $(\frac{r}{2}, \frac{h}{2})$ and travels a length of $2\pi\frac{r}{2}=\pi r$. Since the area of $A$ is $rh$ we get $rh(\pi r)=\pi r^2h$